# What is the precision value needed for Oracle for an Int32?

Tags: c#, oracle

I have a need to store a CRC signed Int32 value in Oracle.  What precision should I use for that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since the max value of a `signed int` is 2,147,483,647 you'd use a precision of 10.

Answer (score 3):

32 bits can store 2^32 or slightly more than 4,000,000,000 different numbers, so you'll need a `NUMBER(10, 0)`.